# py2app doesn't package 'google-api-core'

Tags: setuptools, py2app

I built the app with `python setup.py py2app` and then ran it via the CLI with `./dist/appName.app/Contents/MacOS/appName`, and then got this error:

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-core' distribution was not found and is required by the application

I did some digging into the site-packages and google-api-core dist is just a wheel that further installs into a single "google" namespace in site-packages as follows:

- google

  - api
  - api-core
  - auth
  - oauth2
  - ...

My question is how can I force py2app to add it? I did read through the recipes documentation but my understanding is py2app only adds recipes that are in py2app.recipes

I'm using Python 3.6.4 and building in the inbuilt virtualenv.

Comment: Yes it is! I built the app with `python setup.py py2app` and then ran it via the CLI with `./dist/appName.app/Contents/MacOS/appName` and that error popped up

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.4 and building in the inbuilt virtualenv environment

Comment: Here's the modulegraph html: https://gist.github.com/pandasa123/a53ec49e0e4f255fda71bc2223889ef1

It looks like `google.api_core` IS being packaged? But could it be a namespace issue? (`google.api_core` vs `google-api-core`

Comment: I am having this same problem - getting an error that the google library can't find the python requests package